# When To Use A View Vs. A New Project

Tags: python, django

This is a non-specific question about best practice in Django. Also note when I say "app" I'm referring to Django's definition of apps within a project.

How should you go about deciding when to use a new view and when to create an entirely new app? In theory, you can have a simple webapp running entirely on one views.py for an existing app.

So how do you go about deciding when to branch off to a new app or just add a new function in your views.py? Is it just whatever makes the most sense?

Comment: "Is it just whatever makes the most sense?" Yes. It's just code structure, so do whatever makes sense and aids code maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on your application.
If you are an only developer working on project .
It is advisable to write one view for each web page or event.

If you have multiple developers in your house you can split the view if you want to make a part of it reusable or something like that.

Again its all about how your team work,better stick to the same style for the entire project

all the best

Comment: Thanks a ton! It's just me now, but we are planning on bringing on more as time goes on and I don't want to go back and repair poorly structured code.